# How to set header to full screen mode in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I set attribute `data-fullscreen="true"` for header, it works fine. But I do need to do this in runtime, when I receive some event. I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[data-role=header]").attr("data-fullscreen", "true");
});
```

In Chrome's element inspection the attribute `data-fullscreen` changes to `true`, but nothing happens with header. Does anyone know another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/HCcUe/

And code example:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('[data-role="header"]').attr({'data-fullscreen':'true','data-position':'fixed'}).html('<h3>Test</h3>');
    $('#index').trigger('pagecreate');                                    
});
```

Use pageshow or pagebeforeshow page event to set this attributes. Also do not use document ready with jQuery Mobile, here you will find why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600

Comment: Great! Thank you, @Gajotres. My mistake was that I didn't call `.trigger('pagecreate')`.

Comment: I faced with a new problem. Now I cant't switch from fullscreen to normal mode. Here's my code, based on your example: http://jsfiddle.net/sidd92/QcgMZ Enable works, but disable doesn't. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Lets continue this discussion through mail, contact me at dragan.gaic@gmail.com , I will send you a fix